# Converting a shapefile from decimal degrees to UTM (km) in R

Tags: shapefile, r, vector, sf

The code that I have below seems like it works in converting my vector `roads` which is in decimal degrees into a UTM CRS so that I can more easily work on the data in kilometers rather than decimal degrees.

However, upon inspecting `roads.UTM` I can see that the extent of the SpatialLinesDataFrame is still in decimal degrees, `extent: 24.41195, 32.79441, -17.92888, -9.358345  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`, and yet the CRS says it's in `+proj=UTM`.

How can I convert `roads` into UTM so that the extent is in UTM and not decimal degrees?

If you want to download the roads shape file you may do so [here](https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/zambia-roads): It is a shape file from the World Bank, which you can download by click on the link: ["Download Zipped Shapefile Here: Zambia Roads"](https://development-data-hub-s3-public.s3.amazonaws.com/ddhfiles/99938/geospatial/AICD/Roads/zambia_roads.zip).

Here is the code I have:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(sf)
roads<-readShapeSpatial("Zambia_Roads.shp")
crs(roads)
proj4string(roads) <- "+init=epsg:32735 +proj=utm +zone=35 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
roads.UTM<-spTransform(roads, CRS("+init=epsg:32735 +proj=utm +zone=35 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
roads.UTM
```

Comment: It seems as if the wrong projection was assigned. You should be able to replace the defective .prj with a correct one, then project it to UTM.

Comment: @Vince I'm not sure what you mean.. is there something wrong with the code as I've written it or something that I need to add?

Comment: Assigning the desired projection instead of the correct one is the cause one of the most common questions here in GIS SE.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure what you mean though.

Comment: On the 4th line you query the CRS of the object, which presumably tells you 4326. On the next line you *assign* the CRS 32735, which does not actually reproject it. The spTransform then does nothing to the geometries of the objects since you've (incorrectly) told `sf` that the projections is already 32735. Remove the 5th line and it will work.

Comment: Actually the CRS of roads originally isn't 4326, it's NA, which is why I can't run the 5th line directly. If I remove the fourth line and run the fifth I get the error `Error in spTransform(xSP, CRSobj, ...) : 
  No transformation possible from NA from reference system`

Comment: Note that UTM has length unit meters — not kilometers.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the comments I figured out that I needed to set `proj4string(roads)<-" +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"` instead of the CRS I wanted to project to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using maptools to read in the roads file and it seems that the particular function is not being maintained. If you are using library(sf) you can read the data directly into a simple features data.frame

Try:

```
library (sf)
roads.geo <- st_read("Zambia_Roads.shp")
roads.utm <- st_transform (roads.geo, crs = 32735)
```

on the other hand, if you need to re-assign a coordinate system try:

```
library (sf)
roads.geo <- st_read("Zambia_Roads.shp")
st_set_crs(roads.geo, value = 4326)       # setting crs to WGS84
roads.utm <- st_transform (roads.geo, crs = 32735)
```

you need to be aware though, that the produces a different class (sf data frame) to the SpatialLinesDataFrame you might be used to. If you can, get hold of the documentation for sf from CRAN to get a list of the host of functions available.

Comment: Thanks for this but I wanted to stick with a SpatialLinesDataFrame.